# Java Jakarta Mail not accepting emoji on subject

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail

I´m trying to send alerts through jakarta mail, using a gmail account and for this I wanted to send a  emoji on the subject.

```
Session session = Session.getInstance(properties, new Authenticator() {
    @Override
    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
        return new PasswordAuthentication(usr, pass);
    }
});

try {
    Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
    message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("httpstatusmonitor@gmail.com"));

    Address[] toUser = InternetAddress
            .parse(toEmail);

    message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, toUser);
    message.setSubject("\uD83D\uDEA8"+" This is an alert "+"\uD83D\uDEA8");
    message.setContent(messageText, "text/html; charset=utf-8");

    Transport.send(message);
}
```

I´ve tried every answer about this but I receive a ? every time I try to send it via tomcat server, using a psvm it is functional to use something like "\uD83D\uDEA8"+" This is an alert "+"\uD83D\uDEA8".

Comment: What does `System.out.println(java.nio.charset.Charset.defaultCharset());` print?

Comment: it prints UTF-8

Comment: And you're running that on the machine from which Java is sending the mail?

Comment: Yes, I am running that on the same machine

Comment: Can you post the source of a problematic mail, headers and all *formatted as code*

Comment: `message.setSubject("=?UTF-8?Q?Smiley_subject_=F0=9F=9A=A8?=");` might be interesting

Answer (score 0):

Don't upcast MimeMessage to Message.  MimeMessage has a method [`MimeMessage.setSubject(String subject, String charset)`](https://jakartaee.github.io/mail-api/docs/api/jakarta.mail/jakarta/mail/internet/MimeMessage.html#setSubject(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)) which takes the charset as an additional parameter.

```
Session session = Session.getInstance(properties, new Authenticator() {
    @Override
    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
        return new PasswordAuthentication(usr, pass);
    }
});

try {
    MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
    message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("httpstatusmonitor@gmail.com"));

    Address[] toUser = InternetAddress
            .parse(toEmail);

    message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, toUser);
    message.setSubject("\uD83D\uDEA8"+" This is an alert "+"\uD83D\uDEA8", "UTF-8");
    message.setContent(messageText, "text/html; charset=utf-8");

    Transport.send(message);
}
```